# PHP echo quote syntax error

Tags: php

I have what most likely is a very simple question for you experienced `PHP` developers out there, I am trying to add some `PHP` code to a `PDF` generation software that I am currently using.

The issue that I am having I believe lies in my quotes. I have tried single quotes, double quotes with a single quote on the outside, escaping the `php`, just about everything that I could think of, still no luck.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php 
// add code to check if data
if (!empty($form_data['field'][39]))
{

echo "<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php foreach($form_data['field'][274] as $url):?> <img src="<?php echo str_replace(site_url(), ABSPATH, $url); ?>" width="250px" /> <?php endforeach; ?  >
 </div>";
?>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this, when there is data entered into 'field' 39, it should echo the generated image below. This image though is generated dynamically, so I need to replace the URL as such so I have the str replace for the site url, but I am unsure of which quotes to change throughout this echo, all my attempts have just broken the PDF that is generated.

Comment: Missing `";` after `echo "<div style="text-align:center;">`, and you should either switch to single-quotes on the outer ones there, or escape the double ones inside: `echo "<div style=\"text-align:center;\">";` - and the `"; ?>` at the end are redundant, you're not in PHP there. (But you have a space between `?  >` after the `endforeach;`)

Comment: also where is your if condition is closed?

Comment: Also why you generate html code with php? You should prepare your output divs beforehand and then use the js or post the html code outside of php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain that this is correct in your context, but this is at least syntactically correct. Try it.

```
<?php
// add code to check if data
    if (!empty($form_data['field'][39]))
    {

        echo "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
            foreach($form_data['field'][274] as $url):
         ?>
            <img src="<?php echo str_replace(site_url(), ABSPATH, $url); ?>" width="250px" />
         <?php
            endforeach;
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much bassxzero,
Your solution worked excellently. I appreciate your prompt reply.